# Different answer to GET request if there is an Authorization header provided

Tags: rest, authorization, token, api-design, bearer-token

My REST API allows `GET` requests to all resources, which are tests and questions, and authorizes only `PATCH`, `POST`, and `DELETE` requests using a Bearer token. Users can access all the resources by using the URL `<host>/api/tests`, or an individual one by `<host>/api/tests/<id of test>`. My API also supports filters such as `<host>/api/tests?uploaderId=<id of uploader>`.

However, I encountered a problem. If I wanted to filter only the tests of a specific user, for example, to show only them on their home page, I need to know the user's ID to supply it as a value for the `uploaderId` parameter. I should not decode the token on the client-side to get the user's ID. Therefore, I came up with the following idea: if the `GET` request contains an `Authorization` header, the API will return only the items of the user whose token was provided. If the `GET` request doesn't contain an `Authorization` header, the API will return all items.

Does this solution violate REST principles?

In hindsight, I probably should have authorized `GET` requests as well, while sharing tests could be done by creating an endpoint that takes a code. I also probably should have gone for requests like `<host>/api/users/<id>/tests`. However, I don't have the time to make drastic changes. Moreover, this is a university project, not a real product.

What's the real-life practice in such situations? Is there a better solution than mine that doesn't require a complete restructuring of the API?